# Name of this shape derived from a convex body by reflections?

Tags: reference-request, metric-geometry

Let $P$ be a convex polygon, and $x \in P$ a point inside $P$.
Reflect $x$ in each edge of $P$, and connect the reflections in the same order
as the edges, producing a new polygon $P^*$. For example:

---

[image: ReflPt2]

         

<sup>The blue polygon is $P$. The red polygon is $P^*$.</sup>

---

Note that $P^*$ is not necessarily convex; 
nor is it always true that $P^* \supset P$.

> Does this reflected object have a name in the literature?
>   Perhaps for (smooth) convex bodies, and perhaps in arbitrary dimensions?

It could as well be defined for nonconvex $P$.
I would name it the *reflect* of $P$ with respect to $x$.
This object has come up in my work, and it would be useful to know
if there is any literature on its properties.

Comment: Yes, it can be seen as a particular case of a Voronoi cell.

Comment: Have a look at (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram). You will see that each "Voronoi cell" has a "seed" in it and that the seeds of the neighouring cells are symmetrical with respect to the sides.

Comment: @JeanMarie: Thank you for that observation!